# Good ways to transparent redirect site to port 8080?

Tags: linux, browser, webserver, transparency, httpd

Currently my home internet provider does not allow services on ports 1 to 1024 but allow the use of high ports to whatever users want to do and I was wondering what ways are there to mask my webserver @ ip:8080 and yet maintain the servernames ?

For example currently if I use myexample.com:8080 it will open just fine but I know there some ways to make it look like if port 8080 never existed, one example of this would be using a proxy server somewhere else to redirect the access but I don't have one available nor money to use for this.

In the above case what would happen is that when user hitted the proxy server it would redirect and query my server so user would never know 2nd server existed at all.

Another way would be creating a page somewhere else and put your site as a iframe or frame which would hide it but may be a problem to some browsers etc...

- So I belive the question here is what
  options do I have to mask my server
  at 8080 to look like a transparent
  webserver ?

**While I do know this seems a bit technical I belive the place to ask this question would be here instead of serverfault, but if the majority does not think that please move the topic.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up to make it a transparent site was to rent a VPS and make a reverse proxy server with [nginx](http://www.nginx.org/) and their domain pointing to it, so it forwards the request to my clint server ip in a transparent way.

Answer (score 1):

I know of [DynDNS's WebHop](http://www.dyndns.com/services/webredirect/) service.  Unfortunately when you use the option to make it invisible you end up with a URL bar that doesn't change.

Comment: +1 thanks, I didnt know of this service from dyndns but if possible I am looking for a transparent solution more similar to a proxy.